# Practical: deployment of application with .sql files

Tags: java

I am developing an application that will make heavy use of .sql files. While I am just at the beginning of development, I want to make sure I am going in the right direction to avoid re-coding later. Much like java source code is not meant for the end user to be seen, neither are .sql files and commands. My main goal is to hide them from the end user. My approach is as follows, and I am seeking alternative approaches and suggestions:

Write a small program that loops through all .sql files in a directory and stores the contents into a java.util.map using bufferedInputStream. The Map will be constructed with = new HashMap(, ). (I believe this is correct syntax). The key will be the .sql file name and value will be the .sql file contents. Then, serialize the Map object into a single file (say "SQLBin.bin") using ObjectOutputStream. Place the SQLBin.bin file into the resources folder of the main project and then use .getResourceAsStream() to access it and recreate a Map object in the main application. This will then allow me to access the SQL commands by simply referring to the .sql file by name in the Map object.

PS: I am relatively new to java. So please be extra clear.

Comment: What would all these SQL statements do? Why not keep them directly in the Java source code so you don't have to do the .sql-files-hashmap-serialization-resource-loading dance every time you change something?

Comment: I understand you want to separate the java code from the sql code. You should use stored procedures instead .sql files.

Comment: The SQL statements will interact with the database... they will be prepared statements that will insert into the DB strings etc that the user wants to store and the retreive information based on user desires - button clicks etc. I don't want to keep them directly in java code because for testing purposes, it is easier to just run a .sql file through the database. Seconds reason is that if the statement is long, so a bunch of statements to create a schema for example would not be pleasent to work with in java code. You would need to use " + " everywhere to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know much about stored procedures. Would this not be on the server side? The server will be embeded in the application as a library, if that helps.

Comment: Well, if you are going to use sqlite or any database that doesn't support stored procedures then the .sql files are good solution. About stored procedures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

Comment: As for schema generation, `.sql` files are indeed a good idea. I would still store them as plain text files and load them direclty as resources, though -- users won't see resource files in a JAR (and if they really start looking, serialization won't stop them).

Comment: As for the prepared statements, I don't see any difference in copying them out of a `.java` or `.sql` file into your favorite SQL tool -- I find it much easier to keep my SQL close to where I set the parameters.

Comment: Thank you Philipp Reichart for your response. I agree with you that storing .sql files as plain text and loading them as resources is a good approach. Would you be willing to provide a code snippet that would make it easy to refer to different files in different places? For example, for the SQLBin.bin approach, I have the following: objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/SQL/SQLBin.bin")); The reason I am using Map is to make it easy to refer to the SQL code that I want.

Answer (score 1):

You have an interesting technique; however, it is not clear what problem you intend to solve.

If you want to hide the SQL from the end user, you don't need to do all of this; just embed the SQL into a statement "string array" in a class and be done with it.  But even such a solution might not be desirable depending on the true problem you are attempting to solve.

Also, some places really want to look at your SQL, because a database server isn't like a JVM.  Your SQL can impact the correct operation of other mission critical programs.  SQL servers may require manual configuration to grant you access.  SQL servers may be monitored 24 / 7 for conditions that lead to excessive memory consumption or excessive use of CPU cycles.  Professionals might rewrite your statements or tune the server to better accommodate unforeseen issues.

With a JVM the resource is less of a shared resource, and thus there's less potential for damage, in the worst case, you kill the offending JVM process, which rarely impacts the other processes that weren't explicitly written to integrate with yours.

Comment: I intend to solve 2 main problems: 1 - hide SQL from the users to stop them from changing it (accidentally). 2 - make it easy for me to point to a particular SQL statement when preparing a prepared statement. Embedding in a string array is not as practical because I would prefer to use SQL development tools that have code highlighting, completion etc. I would then have to copy and paste all the code into the java code... which will work but is cumbersome. And to clarify, the SQL server will in fact be apache derby in imbedded mode as a library.

Comment: It seems Apache Derby supports stored procedures so I encourage you to use them: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/rrefcreateprocedurestatement.html
(Although I've never used Derby...)

Comment: @DavidEG Thank you so much DavidEG for your advice.